# How to get this grid normal height?

Tags: output-formatting, grid-layouts, size, scaling

When I execute this

```
Grid[{{x, x}, {SpanFromAbove, x}, {SpanFromAbove, x}}, 
 ItemSize -> {{Automatic}, 
  {Automatic, {1 -> Scaled[0.2], 2 -> Scaled[0.4], 3 -> Scaled[0.4]}}}, 
 Frame -> All, 
 Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Spacings -> {{2}, {1}}]
```

I get an extremely tall grid instead of a normal height grid.  Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Version 10.0.1 Win8.1 64bit

## **Update**

This just keeps getting worse.  I am have used a `Pane` as some have suggested that the grid needs a sized container for it to work with `Scaled`. I get back a truncated grid.  This is really baffling.  Any ideas how to get this to work.

```
Pane[
 Grid[{{x, x}, {SpanFromAbove, x}, {SpanFromAbove, x}}, 
  ItemSize -> {{{Scaled[0.5]}}, 
   {Automatic, {1 -> Scaled[0.2], 2 -> Scaled[0.4], 3 -> Scaled[0.4]}}}, 
  Frame -> All, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Spacings -> {{1}, {1}}], 
 ImageSize -> {432, 216}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It gives a cut off grid. ??? I can just make out the top of the "x" in the first column. It shouldn't be this difficult to have a grid a prescribed size and scale some rows within it.  I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Unles you wrap `Grid` with something with set size, `Scaled` will refer to WindowSize.

Comment: So I need to wrap it in a `Pane` or `Panel` and that will work?

Comment: @Edmund The qustion is, what do you need?

Comment: @Silvia Edmund set `Item` height not width. *specx* here is `{Automatic}` and it is width of items. But for *specy* he set explicitly `1->Scaled[.4]` etc. what means "first row heigth 40% of enclosing region.

Comment: @Silvia But I agree, the whole layout management is broken. For example here, `Scaled` takes something different into account: `Framed["x", ImageSize -> {Scaled@1, Scaled@1}]`

Comment: @Kuba You're right! I must have read/written it with an automatic `StringReplace[stuff, "width" -> "size"]` built in my brain! :O

Comment: @Kuba I have a chart in position {1,1} and some grids in each of the rows of column 2.  I'd just like the rows in column 2 have heights as a percentage of the height `Grid` comes up with when `ItemSize` is omitted.  When the chart is made its width is specified but height is `Automatic` so I don't know how tall it is.  Also, the combined height of the 3 grid tables is greater than the height of the chart.  I though `Grid` would use the total height it gets when no `ItemSize` option is given and then scale the rows using that height.  But now I know it doesn't do this.

Comment: @Edmund are you sure there is no way to get your chart height? It may be tough without that. Can't you specify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice, unless it is really basic problem, do **not use `SpanFrom~`**. Usually you will face "issues" like that. Next time try with nested `Grids`.

Like I've said, the whole layout management is broken and everyone who tried do something more complex than simple grid with automatic options will agree.

This is just another example, your case works if vertical heights sum up to: `.5`...

```
Framed[
 Grid[{
       {x, x},
       {SpanFromAbove, x},
       {SpanFromAbove, x}},
  ItemSize -> {
               {{Scaled@.499}},                  (*specX*)
               {Scaled@.1, Scaled@.2, Scaled@.2} (*specY*)
    }, Frame -> All, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
 , 
     ImageSize -> {432, 216}, FrameMargins -> 0, Alignment -> {Left, Top}]
```

> [image]